# Some integer solutions for $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking for integer solutions to the equation $a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2$ such that $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$.

Comment: These are known as [pythagorean quadruples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_quadruple)

Comment: If you just want a few ones, select $b$ and $c$ arbitrarily such that $b^2+c^2$ is odd, and let $a=\frac{b^2+c^2-1}2$, $d=a+1$.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2088960/451007.

Comment: I've found the answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088960/solutions-for-a2b2c2-d2

Comment: @Mason: The accepted answer does say that is describes the "primitive" solutions, which is another word for the gcd condition. If it is correct, then there are no _pairwise_ coprime solutions.

Comment: The problem as set has solutions with $c=0$ for example, which we already know.

Comment: Take any four integers $m,n,p,q$ with $\gcd(m,n,p,q)=1$ and $m+n+p+q$ odd. Those are the only rules. Then
$$ a = m^2 + n^2 - p^2 - q^2, $$
$$ b = 2 (mq+np),  $$
$$ c = 2(nq -mp),  $$
$$ d = m^2 + n^2 + p^2 + q^2 $$